# changing jar file gave cannot find symbol, incompatible types

Tags: eclipse, jar

I just use commons-codec-1.5.jar from commons-codec-1.3.jar in my project. But when I compile the project, the compiler is complaining like it doesn't know the new features of 1.5 jar.

I cleaned my project.
I remove the old jar from build path.
and add new jar.
and also included new jar in build.xml. still complaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you still have an old copy in your WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: yah. I forget to remove it :)